# A Better way to do extract items based on multiple criteria?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a range of data that is about 40,000-60,000 rows, in the following format:

```
CustomerID | Item_Code | Product
```

I need to select all **CustomerID** which have a match for both a specific **Item_code** and **Product**, which is usually less than 1,000 rows.

I wrote the following formula, which is pasted as an **array formula:**

```
=IFERROR(
         INDEX(
               MyDataRange,
               SMALL(
                     IF(
                           (Item_Code=Item_CodeRange)*(Product=ProductRange),
                           ROW(Item_Code)-ROW($C$2)+1,
                           ROW($C$100000)
                       ),
                     ROW()-1
                    ),
               1
              ), 
        0)
```

which indexes my data and returns items that match both the "**Item_CodeRange**" and "**ProductRange**" which are named ranges changed with `VBA`. the "`Small(`" and "`row(`" part of the formula simply puts them in order from smallest to largest based on where they are in the array.

I am pasting this formula a couple times a minute for each combination **Item_codeRange** and **DayRange** I need to iterate through, of which there are about 250 combinations.  It is this array formula that is taking up most of the time in my program.

*Is there a better way to query this information to maximize speed?*

Comment: @pnuts I have tried a pivottable solution but having to loop through all the possible criteria to set them 'visible=false' ends up taking longer than the array formula.

Comment: I second Sid's suggestion for autofilter. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Non-VBA Method**

You can manually set the Autofilter. To learn more about Autofilter see [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx)

**VBA Method**

Lets say your worksheet looks like this.

[image]

Use this code. Please note that this is just a sample code and you will have to edit it to suit your case.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim CustomerID As String, Item_Code As String, Product As String

    Dim lRow As Long

    CustomerID = "100"
    Item_Code = "ABC"
    Product = "Blah Blah"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set MyRange = .Range("A1:C" & lRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With MyRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & CustomerID
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & Item_Code
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=" & Product
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        '.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thank you siddharth, autofilter is the way to go and it is much faster than a pivottable!